# Evento al hacer click en un jTextField - Java

Tags: java, eventos, jtextfield

```js
public class Modificar_cliente extends javax.swing.JDialog implements FocusListener{
    /**
     * Constructor de la clase Modificar_cliente.
     * @param parent
     * @param modal 
     */
    public Modificar_cliente(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);
        
        //Cargamos los DNIs en el jComboBox llamado "jComboBox_DNIs".
        //Declaramos un arrayList de Strings llamado "dni".
        ArrayList<String> dnis = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Cargamos los valores de la función "cargar_dni" de Conexiones.java en el arrayList "dni".
        dnis = Conexiones.cargar_dni();
        //Creamos un iterator para recorrer el ArrayList.
        Iterator<String> i = dnis.iterator();
        //Dato inicial del jComboBox_DNIs
        jComboBox_DNIs.addItem("Seleccione un DNI...");
        //Recorremos el iterator "i".
        while(i.hasNext()){
            //Añadimos a los items cada dni.
            jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Evento en el cual volvemos a la pantalla anterior. Cerrando el JDialog actual
     * gracias al método dispose().
     * @param evt 
     */
    private void button_cancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        //Cerramos la ventana actual con el metodo dispose().
        this.dispose();
    }                                               

    /**
     * Limpiamos los componentes de la interfaz necesarios.
     * @param evt 
     */
    private void button_limpiarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        //Sólo deberemos limpiar la direccion, el teléfono, la ciudad y el email.
        textfield_telefono.setText("");
        textfield_direccion.setText("");
        textfield_ciudad.setText("");
        textfield_email.setText("");
    }                                              

    /**
     * Cargamos en un jComboBox los DNIs existentes en la base de datos.
     * Posteriormente cargaremos el resto de los datos en campos jTextField.
     * @param evt 
     */
    private void jComboBox_DNIsItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                
        //Recogemos en la variable "dni" el valor seleccionado en el combobox con el método "getSelectedItem()".
        String dni = (String) jComboBox_DNIs.getSelectedItem();
        //Si el index del jComboBox_DNIs es distinto de cero, existe DNI y entonces...
        if(jComboBox_DNIs.getSelectedIndex()!=0) {
            button_OK.setVisible(true);
            button_limpiar.setVisible(true);
            JPanel_Cliente.setVisible(true);
            //Guardamos en un objecto "datos_dni" los datos del dni gracias a la función "Conexiones.datos_de_un_dni(dni);".
            Object[] datos_dni = Conexiones.datos_de_un_dni(dni);
            //Sólo son campos no editables el nombre y apellidos.
            textfield_nombre.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[0]));
            textfield_nombre.setEditable(false);
            //textfield_nombre.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            textfield_nombre.setBackground(Color.decode("0xC8C7C6"));
            textfield_apellidos.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[1]));
            textfield_apellidos.setEditable(false);
            //textfield_apellidos.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            textfield_apellidos.setBackground(Color.decode("0xC8C7C6"));
            //El resto de campos sí son editables.
            textfield_telefono.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[2]));
            textfield_direccion.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[3]));
            textfield_ciudad.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[4]));
            textfield_email.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[5]));
            button_OK.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            button_OK.setVisible(false);
            button_limpiar.setVisible(false);
            JPanel_Cliente.setVisible(false);
        }
    }                                               

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
            JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            field.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
            JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Modificar los datos de un cliente seleccionado mediante un DNI.
     * @param evt 
     */
    private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //Atributos generales para el cliente.
        String email = textfield_email.getText();
        String nombre = textfield_nombre.getText();
        String apellidos = textfield_apellidos.getText();
        String DNI = (String) jComboBox_DNIs.getSelectedItem();
        String telefono = textfield_telefono.getText();
        String direccion = textfield_direccion.getText();
        String ciudad = textfield_ciudad.getText();

        //Comprobamos que están todos los datos insertados...
        if (!textfield_email.getText().isEmpty() && !textfield_telefono.getText().isEmpty() && !textfield_direccion.getText().isEmpty() 
            && !textfield_ciudad.getText().isEmpty() ) {
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(email, nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad);
            //Llamamos al método modificar_cliente() para modificar el cliente en la base de datos.
            Conexiones.modificar_cliente(cliente);
            dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!", "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Tengo un formulario de datos en un `JFrame` de Java donde quiero modificar unos datos.

**Al hacer click en cada** `JTextField` o entre el foco en el `JTextField` (tabulando con `TAB`) quiero que **se active el fondo del** `JTextField` de un color llamativo para saber que estamos en dicho `JTextField`.

**Y al salirnos del** `JTextField`, **desactivarlo** y activar del mismo color el que ahora lo esté.

Los `JTextField` se llaman: `jTextField_email, jTextField_telefono, jTextField_direccion, jTextField_ciudad.`

Bien, creo que el evento que realiza esto es: `focusGained()` y `focusLost()`.

```
private void textfield_emailFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  textfield_email.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

private void textfield_emailFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  textfield_email.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Mi cuestión es:

**¿Tengo que hacer estas operaciones por cada** `JTextField` **o existe una forma que agregue todos los** `JTextField` **y compruebe si se pulsó en uno u en otro? Porque si tenemos 200...**

Tengo los `JTextField` dentro de un `JPanel` llamado `JPanel_Cliente`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de agregar una solución que si funciona sin tener que agregar uno por uno los listeners a los campos de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es poner a tu clase de tipo `JFrame` a implementar la interfaz `java.awt.event.FocusListener` e implementar los métodos que esta define (`focusGained(FocusEvent)` y `focusLost(FocusEvent)`).

Dentro de estos método solo tienes que comprobar que la fuente del evento (el componente desde el que se originó) sea de tipo `JTextField` y si es así le modificas el fondo de acuerdo a como necesites. De este modo puedes tener la cantidad de `JTextField`s que necesites, incluso generarlos dinámicamente en tiempo de ejecución, sin necesidad de agregar un listener a cada uno.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EjemploFoco extends JFrame implements FocusListener {
    // Código de la clase

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
            JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            field.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
            JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Manejo global de los eventos sin necesidad de agregar uno a uno los listeners

Puesto que la solución anterior efectivamente requiere que se agregue el listener a cada campo de texto **manualmente**, como muy acertadamente comenta @JonnyTB, agrego una solución que si nos permite escuchar todos los eventos de foco sin tener el requerimiento anterior.

Esta solución lo que hace es agregar un listener que será Global a la aplicación, por lo que será capaz de escuchar y manejar **TODOS** los eventos que en esta se disparen.

Para evitar escuchar eventos de otras ventanas lo que hacemos es comprobar dentro del listener que la ventana que tiene el foco sea la que contiene los campos a procesar.

Agrego el código completo de ejemplo con comentarios en las partes clave.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDialog extends JFrame {

    private final AWTEventListener globalFocusListener;
    private MyDialog self;

    public MyDialog() {
        super("Global focus listener");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // OJO: Sin hacer esto no podemos comprobar dentro del listener
        // si esta venta atiene el foco
        self = this;

        // Este es el listener puede capturar TODOS los eventos de foco que se 
        // disparen desde cualquier componente de la aplicación, no solo de la
        // ventana, por lo que es necesario comprobar si la ventana activa es
        // esta para procesar sus campos y no los de otra
        globalFocusListener = new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                // Solo ejecuto el código si la ventana tiene el foco
                if (self.isFocused()) {
                    if (event instanceof FocusEvent) {
                        FocusEvent focusEvent = (FocusEvent) event;

                        if (focusEvent.getSource() instanceof JTextField) {
                            JTextField field = (JTextField) focusEvent.getSource();

                            if (focusEvent.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED) {
                                field.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            } else if (focusEvent.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST) {
                                field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Para eliminar el listener cuando cierre la ventana
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(globalFocusListener);
            }
        });

        setSize(300, 150);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        // Agrego los campos de texto a la ventana sin indicar listener alguno
        panel.add(new JTextField(10));
        panel.add(new JTextField(10));
        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        add(panel);

        // Agrega el listener global a la aplicación
        startListeningFocusEvents();
    }

    private void startListeningFocusEvents() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .addAWTEventListener(globalFocusListener, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    public static void main(String[] dario){
        new MyDialog().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Me quedo igual que el anterior usuario. La lógica es correcta, compila, pero no me lo lanza el programa.... Pongo mi código completo.

Comment: No cambia de color los campos, qué extraño.

Comment: @omaza1990 que raro, yo lo probé antes de compartir la solución. Estoy casi seguro de que tu problema está en que los campos de texto no son de tipo `JTextField` y por lo tanto nunca se cumple la condición del `if`. Si quieres agrega un `System.out.println("Entró")` justo antes de cada `if` y verás como imprime el texto correctamente.

Answer (score 3):

De ser 200 campos la tarea es engorrosa.
Puedo proponer una solución que consiste en usar una clase por ejemplo `Field` que herede de `JTextField` sobre-escribiendo los métodos `focusGained` y `focusLost` de `FocusListener` para luego ir creando los N componentes manual o dinámicamente a partir de `Field`, quiero decir:

```
public class Field extends JTextField {
  public Field() {
    addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {
      @Override
      public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      }
      @Override
      public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Luego en alguna parte del programa:

```
Field jTextField_email=new Field();
Field jTextField_telefono=new Field();
Field jTextField_direccion=new Field();
Field jTextField_ciudad=new Field();
```

De éste modo cada componente `Field` creado ya incorpora su comportamiento para cambiar su color de fondo al tener o no tener el foco.

**EDITO**

Ya que la implementacion esta hecha via `implements FocusListener` muy probablemente debes pasarle a cada componente el `FocusListener` del `JDialog` (*supongo que es en `initComponents` donde se instancian los campos*)

```
private void initComponents() {
  //...
  textfield_telefono.addFocusListener(this);
  textfield_direccion.addFocusListener(this);
  textfield_ciudad.addFocusListener(this);
  textfield_email.addFocusListener(this);
  //...
}
```

Comment: He entendido e importado tu contestación a mi programa, me compila sin errores pero no realiza las operaciones. No sé dónde estaría el error lógico del programa.

Comment: No debería dar problema alguno, sin embargo seria mejor si muestras como has implementado el código.

Comment: Añado mi código a la pregunta @JohnnyTB

Comment: Recién he ampliado la respuesta, con una solución alternativa.

Comment: No es necesario agregar el listener a cada campo, la solución plateada es capaz de capturar cualquier evento de foco que se haya generado en cualquier componente la ventana.

Comment: @JohnnyTB Con esa aportación de psarle a cada componente el FocusListener, funciona. Sí.

Comment: Si un componente necesita hacer uso del `FocusListener` entonces se lo debe registrar a través del `addFocusListener`, es totalmente necesario. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html

Comment: @JohnnyTB tienes toda la razón, SWING no funciona de ese modo. Por cosas tan triviales como esta prefiero JavaFX xD.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes manejarlo antes de los listeners, sobre-escribiendo el método `processFocusEvent()`:

```
public class FocusColorTextField extends JTextField{

    protected Color focusColor = null;
    protected Color defaultColor = null;

    public FocusColorTextField(){
        this(Color.WHITE,Color.WHITE);
    }

    public FocusColorTextField(Color defaultColor, Color focusColor){
        super();
        this.setBackground(defaultColor);
        this.setFocusBackground(focusColor);
    }

    public void setFocusBackground(Color bg){
        this.focusColor = bg;
    }

    protected void processFocusEvent(FocusEvent e){
        if( e.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED )
            this.setBackground(this.focusColor);
        else
            this.setBackground(this.defaultColor);
        super.processFocusEvent(e);
    }

}
```

Al crear la instancia puedes enviar en el primer argumento el color cuando no  tiene foco, y en el segundo color cuando tenga el foco:

```
JTextField jTextField_email = new FocusColorTextField(Color.WHITE,Color.YELLOW);
```

O también puedes usar el método `setFocusBackground()` en otro momento;

```
FocusColorTextField jTextField_telefono = FocusColorTextField();
...
jTextField_telefono.setFocusBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```